# Custom Layer add_update() function error: takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: keras, call, layer, loss-function

I have a customlayer code:

```
class CenterLossLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, alpha=0.5, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.alpha = alpha

        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.centers = self.add_weight(name='centers',
                               shape=(10, 2),
                               initializer='uniform',
                               trainable=False)
        super().build(input_shape)
    
    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        delta_centers = K.dot(K.transpose(x[1]), (K.dot(x[1], self.centers) - x[0]))  # 10x2
        center_counts = K.sum(K.transpose(x[1]), axis=1, keepdims=True) + 1  # 10x1
        delta_centers /= center_counts
        new_centers = self.centers - self.alpha * delta_centers
        self.add_update((self.centers, new_centers), x)
```

I try to use this layer like in this [github repo](https://github.com/handongfeng/MNIST-center-loss/blob/master/centerLoss_MNIST.py#L122)

But l have this error message:  self.add_update((self.centers, new_centers), x)
TypeError: add_update() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I don't understand why?